# WPF: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Style' to type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary'

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, exception

I try to re-style TextBoxes in my Control to have the same look for ReadOnly as if they were Disabled.
Last week I could achieve this without any problem like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="TextBoxBorderStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBoxBase}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.56"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

... and use it in TextBoxes like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"
         IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="TextBoxBorderStyle" />
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

I don't remember changing anything in this control in the meantime. (Though I updated Visual Studio 2019 to 16.9.4 today). But when I run my application now, it gives a run time error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException   HResult=0x80131501
> Message='Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Resources'
> threw an exception.' Line number '90' and line position '33'.
> Source=PresentationFramework   StackTrace:    at
> System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e,
> IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.Create_BamlProperty_FrameworkElement_Resources.AnonymousMethod__276_0(object,
> object)
> MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(object, System.Xaml.XamlMember, object)
>
> Inner Exception 1: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Windows.Style' to type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary'.

It works as it should when I copy-paste the style directly into all of the `Textbox.Resources` .
Anyone knows why?
Especially since sharing the `StaticResource` has worked without a problem before.

EDIT: It works as expected in the xaml editor/designer and properly adjusts the style to the view model data without any exception. Only at run time there is a problem.

Comment: Make sure you are targeting same version of Net that you used previously or do a clean build to use latest version of Net.

Comment: I haven't changed the target .NET version (4.7.2), I tried clean+rebuild, close VS, delete the .vs folder, but nothing helped so far. There must be something I'm missing. Weird that it just works at design time (it even nicely responds to changes in my design time view model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either replace `<StaticResource ResourceKey="TextBoxBorderStyle" />` with an actual `Style`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"
         IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderStyle}" />
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

...or change the `TargetType` of your `Style` and simply set the `Style` property of the `TextBox`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxBorderStyle">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBoxBase}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.56"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"
         IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         Style="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderStyle}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. So simple. Still strange why the way I did it behaved different in design and run time. Though I also found out now that our application loads a 3rd party theme dynamically at run time, which is not loaded in the designer, so it uses the default styles and templates at design time, and the 3r party ones at run time (which had no Border child element in the template, so the trigger had no effect - so I set another property/object)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"
             IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="TextBoxBorderStyle" />
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
```

With

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"
             IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Style={DynamicResource TextBoxBorderStyle}/>
```

That should fix the issue. If not, try to reset your resource dictionary by deleting the old style and making a new one by going to that textbox and right-click - Edit Style/Template - Edit a Copy
And then select "Resource Dictionary" and choose your resource dictionary

Comment: Thanks, but the Style is for the TextBox inner Border. Not for the TextBox as a whole, so this will give "'Border' TargetType does not match type of element 'TextBox'". I'm not sure what you mean by 'delete the old style and make a new one' since I am not deriving from nor referring to any custom theme or style. Maybe I forgot to mention the style is defined in the root of the custom control.

Comment: Did you mean creating and using a copy of the default ControlTemplate with an additional trigger to enable the border style forReadOnly? It could be an option, but it would overwrite the current ControlTemplate completely, which might change if another base theme or style is used.

Comment: I meant to make a style for the whole text box. It's not that hard - you can use triggers for that part

Comment: I know. Just the default template adjusts the properties of the border, not that of the textbox and I wanted it to look the same. ( however I found out now that at runtime, a different template is being used, so I need to extract the xaml for that in some way to add a copy of the defined trigger for disabled as a new trigger for readonly)